# Controllable current source

Tags: current-source

I had a pretty straightforward question:
Is it possible to control the current in a circuit using Python?
If yes, what device do we need to do so?
I only possess knowledge on Physics and not on Electrical Engineering, so I would really appreciate if the technical terms used in your answers are simple to understand and if you do use some, then please explain the meaning of that term. Hours of browsing on the internet returned nothing. I did find one article though, but it was probably not what I was looking for so I won't be linking that here.
If we cannot control the current using python, then can we do so using some other programming language?

If the above isn't possible, then how do I set up a current source whose current I can vary at will but not mechanically(i.e., by pressing a button or rotating a dial) and instead using a computer.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**:
In response to @Transistor's queries:

1. Computer Systems available: Windows,Linux and Rpi. But Rpi is the least preferred
2. Current range: 0-2A
3. Hobby, lab or industrial?: Lab
4. Level of precision: I want to try controlling this first, and later think about precision.
   So I hope that I have clarified any context that you guys wanted.
   Now after reading the comments and the answer, I would remind you to kindly elaborate a little more in layman terms as I am not familiar with a lot of Electrical Engineering. Even some reference links will suffice.

**EDIT 2**
Okay so after a lot of browsing, I have gained more knowledge. Jonk says that I can buy a programmable current source. However the issue is that there is no programmable current source that I found. If you know of such a current source, then please tell me the model number/provide a link. Now coming to what I have found. I have found some programmable power sources. Although a programmable power source is something I do not prefer, if there's no programmable current source out there, then here's the idea that I have:
If we operate the Programmable Power Source in CC(Constant Current) mode and then using a Python script and SCPI, I use a for loop in which the current value increases or decreases in every iteration, then I'd be done!
My question is therefore:

1. Is there a programmable current source in the market? A preferred budget would be 25,000 INR. If yes, please tell which one.
2. If answer to question is No, then will the current actually vary in the circuit if I try to implement the idea that I have described about the programmable power supply?

Comment: This is a hardware dependent. (1) What is the computer system? (2) What is the current requirement? (3) What is the maximum voltage required? (4) Hobby, lab or industrial? (5) What level of precision? (6) What's the budget?

Comment: A bench power supply with USB/serial connection and libraries available. Or cards from National Instruments with analog output to control your own bench.

Comment: For a *pretty straightforward question* you do need context.  The comments are asking for context!  Without that your *pretty straightforward question* is unclear and will probably be closed.

Comment: The short answer is Yes. The long answer requires at least some specification of what you need. What current range? what voltage range? A high side drive or low side drive, or floating, or optically isolated from your computer? Some hints might help other offer advice.

Comment: @Tesla You will want some way to program digital values into a DAC, which will produce an analog voltage for you based on the digital value that you program into the DAC. That voltage can then be used to control a circuit (which you need) that can convert the voltage into a current source/sink result into a load. You will need to specify many things. But yes, it can be done using Python if and only if you have such a system that Python can communicate with. This can be over USB. But that's only one possibility of many. You need to specify that, as well.

Comment: I have edited the post and responded to some of the questions you asked. If there's any other clarification that you require, please let me know.

Comment: The edits are good. You missed item 3, the maximum output voltage required. It may help to know what you're powering.

Comment: @Tesla'sCoil Is there a reason why you are not considering commercial power supplies with USB control and drivers for Windows or Linux? This would seem to be the obvious approach. I have here on my desk three Tektronix PS2520G power supplies with GPIB controls. They are old. More modern ones will use USB, likely. But given the level of current you want, I don't understand why you wouldn't just buy something. Is there a budget issue? Or a size issue?

Comment: There are a bunch of microcontrollers that run MicroPython, does that count?

Comment: @jonk I really do not mind purchasing something readymade. The only issue is that I am unable to find some current source which meets the requirements I have. Can you please suggest a model of a "current source" (and not a "power source") that can be controlled using python/software?

Comment: @Transistor and other users, Please note that I have edited the question, please answer it now

Comment: If you want a cheap USB controllable bench power supply with a current source mode, try Korad KD3005P

Answer (score 1):

The main thing you need is a current source that can plug into a computer.

From scratch an MCU controlled current source with a USB-UART bridge. The bridge is a USB adapter that, with the right PC drivers, appears as an RS-232 port (virtual COM port) on the PC. The other end plugs straight into the microcontroller's UART.

That way you can use USB ports in hardware but treat it as the older RS-232/UART/hyperterminal in software. Much easier than using native USB.

Then use python to send terminal commands through the virtual COM port.

Comment: I would have thought that a filtered PWM driving a 0 - 5 V controlled current source would be the way to go.

Comment: @Transistor PWM? From a USB-UART bridge?

Comment: No, but you brought in those constraints, not the OP. I would have gone for some sort of analog I/O solution rather than introduce another MCU. Let's see what the OP comes back with after my OP comment.

Comment: @Transistor Did you miss the part about a computer+Python? I interpreted that as a PC. Unless you know a way to get an analog or PWM straight out of a PC.

Comment: @DKNguyen The sound output comes to mind for analog output. Many motherboards also contain connectors for driving RGB LEDs using PWM. But we don't know what counts as a PC. For all we know, this could be done with a CdS photoresistor and pointing it at PC screen while a Python program draws various shades of white to control the photoresistor. Or it's not a PC but a MCU running micropython, or a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: I saw that OK but thought it could be an RPi or something else. Here's a [USB to PWM module](https://www.yoctopuce.com/EN/products/usb-electrical-interfaces/yocto-pwm-tx) found on a quick web search.

Comment: @Transistor That is true. When I see "not EE"+"scripting language" my brain defaults to PC.

Comment: Python does run on embedded controllers.

Comment: You can use a programmable power supply, many have current limit control as well as voltage.

Comment: You can bitbang PWM on a parallel port, too, not that computers tend to *have* those anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Although RPi is your less preferred computer, it would probably be substantially easier than a typical laptop, since it has a PWM (Pulse Width Modulation) module on it. Like Transistor suggested early on, filtered PWM to a voltage-controlled current source ([basic disussion here](https://circuitdigest.com/electronic-circuits/voltage-controlled-current-source-circuit-using-op-amp)) seems quite straightforward. See diagram below. You use the RPi to output PWM (which you can do in Python), then run a low-pass filter on that output. The resulting filtered voltage is then the input to your voltage-controlled current source.

[image]

If you want to avoid the RPi, then you introduce a step up in complication because you need something to interface with the USB computer output. One example is [this](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2264?gclid=CjwKCAjw4qCKBhAVEiwAkTYsPD8QQ7icjaDIw3i0LaRdjYk6x0G3Fp_hINKC3BzjCcT02ys-CPfc9BoC9wcQAvD_BwE) module, which will enable you to use various types of serial communication through your computer's USB port. You can drive it with some Python libraries. One reasonable choice for serial protocol would be I2C, which is a serial communication protocol used by many integrated circuits (many online references, [here](https://www.circuitbasics.com/basics-of-the-i2c-communication-protocol/) is one). You could, for instance, interface this to a Digital-to-Analog Converter (DAC) that uses I2C, such as [this](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12918) one, which would give you the voltage you need to connect to your voltage-controlled current source.